# Mysql update all rows value with count of same table column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, window-functions

I have following table with data:

```
| predp_id | strp_ID | predp_nas |
| -------- | ------- | --------- |
| 1        | 1       |   null    |
| 2        | 1       |   null    |
| 3        | 1       |   null    |
| 4        | 2       |   null    |
| 5        | 2       |   null    |
| 6        | 3       |   null    |
```

predp_nas column should be count of strp_ID column + 1 for same strp_ID on every row.

I am currently using next query to achieve this on every new insert:

```
INSERT INTO PREDMETIP
    (`strp_ID`, `predp_nas`)
VALUES(
 1, 
 (SELECT counter + 1 FROM (SELECT COUNT(strp_ID) counter FROM PREDMETIP WHERE strp_ID = '1') t)
);
```

This gives me:

```
| predp_id | strp_ID | predp_nas |
| -------- | ------- | --------- |
| 1        | 1       |   null    |
| 2        | 1       |   null    |
| 3        | 1       |   null    |
| 4        | 2       |   null    |
| 5        | 2       |   null    |
| 6        | 3       |   null    |
| 7        | 1       |     4     |
```

But now I have imported large amount of data and I need to update all predp_nas fields at once to give me result:

```
| predp_id | strp_ID | predp_nas |
| -------- | ------- | --------- |
| 1        | 1       |     1     |
| 2        | 1       |     2     |
| 3        | 1       |     3     |
| 4        | 2       |     1     |
| 5        | 2       |     2     |
| 6        | 3       |     1     |
| 7        | 1       |     4     |
```

I have DB fiddle with insert query [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7xsNYHr4eVtnKmvGs7My2q/0) , I am having trouble understanding how to write  query for same thing but to update all fields at once. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `ROW_NUMBER()` (if you're using MySQL 8+), but since your fiddle is on MySQL 5.7 I'm assuming that's your version and so you can emulate it by counting the number of rows for a given `strp_ID` that have a lower `predp_id` and using that to update the table:

```
UPDATE PREDMETIP p1
JOIN (
  SELECT p1.predp_id,
       COUNT(p2.predp_id) + 1 AS rn
  FROM PREDMETIP p1
  LEFT JOIN PREDMETIP p2 ON p2.strp_ID = p1.strp_ID AND p2.predp_id < p1.predp_id
  GROUP BY p1.predp_id
) p2 ON p1.predp_id = p2.predp_id
SET p1.predp_nas = p2.rn
;
SELECT *
FROM PREDMETIP
```

Output after update:

```
predp_id    strp_ID     predp_nas
1           1           1
2           1           2
3           1           3
4           2           1
5           2           2
6           3           1
7           1           4
```

Comment: Watch out for the user variables here... Since *[The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)*, this might not do exactly what you want. There is a technique using a `case` expression to work around that, I do not remember it well.

Comment: @GMB it's fine as a select. The issue is the `ORDER BY` will be ignored if you attempt to use it as a subquery for updating, and so it will start numbering again when it encounters the new row. I've made a note to that effect.

Comment: While this gives me wanted result in select query how to add this into update query to update actual rows? .

Comment: All I could think of is taking the result and making a update query of each result row with editor on computer.

Comment: @Nick: the first expression in the `select` clause checks the value of `@strp_ID`, the second one assigns it. I am quite suspicious about it. It looks a lot like the example given in the docs: *For example, there is no guarantee that `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1` evaluates `@a` first and then performs the assignment.*

Comment: I used this select result and manipulate it on computer to make update query for each row then run on DB. I am reading this discussion and will just note that on 1000+ data rows all results seem right. Ill mark it as answer as it seems right and it is for my DB version.

Comment: @ikiK . . . "seem" is the operator word.  MySQL explicitly does not guarantee that the results are correct.  Sometimes they will be.  Sometimes they won't be.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand the problem and it is bothering me, but seems like I have no other chose currently then to trust it unfortunately, as I don't have MySQL 8. Or looks like I can do  this in excel and then import those numbers additionally or do whole import of data again.

Comment: @ikiK . . . Actually, there are ways to address the problem, but you accepted this answer so there is no incentive to provide a more sustainable answer.

Comment: Wow, you go away for a couple of hours and there's been a complete firestorm. @GMB you have used this identical structure in other answers e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58186125/how-to-show-rows-in-packs-of-three-of-two-tables-in-mysql/58186410#58186410

Comment: @ikiK I've updated the answer with a query which can be used to update and has *no* variables so will be reliable. Sorry about all the drama, I had to go away for a while so wasn't able to respond earlier.

Comment: @Nick: ah ah, that's what happens when MySQL user variables come in the picture (see [this other discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62354347/10676716) for another example of such "firestorm"- yet on a much simpler case!). Yes I did use that before, but, the way I understood the documentation since then, I wouldn't use it that way anymore.

Comment: @GMB well there isn't a variable to be seen any more...

Comment: I see no drama, just educational discussion, and I appreciate all the time given by all to this. Thanks for all replays.

Comment: @Nick: +1 for providing an alternative solution. You might want to have a look at my answer, that provides a solution based on user variables.

Answer (score 2):

You seeem to be looking for an `update` query. If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with `row_number()`:

```
update predmetip p
inner join (
    select p.*, row_number() over(partition by predp_id order by strp_id) rn
    from predmetip p
) p1 on p1.predp_id = p.predp_id and p1.strp_id = p.strp_id
set p.predp_nas = p1.rn
```

---

On the other hand, if you are running a MySQL 5.x version, then one option is to use correlated subqueries, as demonstrated [in Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62384579/10676716). This works fine - and I upvoted Nick's answer - but the performance tends to quickly degrade when the volume of data gets larger, because you need to scan the table for each and every row in the resultset.

You *can* do this with user variables, but it's is tricky: since, as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select` clause is undefined, we need to evaluate and assign in the same expression ; `case` comes handy for this. Another important thing is that we need to order the rows in a subquery *before* variables come into play.

You would write the `select` statement as follows:

```
set @rn := 0, @strp_id = '';
select 
    predp_id,
    strp_id,
    @rn := case 
        when @strp_id  = strp_id then @rn + 1 -- read
        when @strp_id := strp_id then 1       -- assign
    end as predp_nas
from (
      select * 
      from predmetip
      order by strp_id, predp_id
) t
```

You can then turn it to an `update`:

```
set @rn := 0, @strp_id = '';
update predmetip p
inner join (
    select 
        predp_id,
        strp_id,
        @rn := case 
            when @strp_id  = strp_id then @rn + 1
            when @strp_id := strp_id then 1
        end as predp_nas
    from (
          select * 
          from predmetip
          order by strp_id, predp_id
    ) t
) p1 on p1.predp_id = p.predp_id and p1.strp_id = p.strp_id
set p.predp_nas = p1.predp_nas;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7xsNYHr4eVtnKmvGs7My2q/3)** (with credits to Nick for creating it in the first place).

To read more about user variables and their tricks, I recommend  [this excellent answer by Madhur Bhaiya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465111/determine-rank-based-on-multiple-columns-in-mysql), which also contains another interesting blog link.

Comment: Yes I need update, but for lower version of MySQL 5.6.43

Comment: @GMB you were right about the `case` trick (and I should have remembered it), in the same question Gordon also gives an answer using `if` to the same effect (and in fact it was Gordon who prompted Madhur to change his code (it originally looked just like mine). So anyway, +1 for fixing my original answer!